# How to write deadlock-proof upsert T-SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, asp.net-core-webapi, crud

For a web api performing standard CRUD operations against a database :

For the DML CUD operations I could see two strategies at the endpoint :

Strategy 1 : CUD SPs accept params for table keys.  First call read SP to determine if relevant record(s) exist; if not found return 401; if found then proceed with SP insert, update, delete, passing relevant key.

Example : endpoint to add new auto for customer.  Auto table has FK to PK of Customer table.  First call Auto Read SP ( first name, last name, phone, etc. ). If no row found, return 401 + custom message.  If row found, call Auto Update SP passing Customer key.

Strategy 2 : CUD SPs accept properties params and SQL joins to other tables ( if relevant ).

Example : same endpoint.  Single call to Auto Insert SP with with params auto make, model, year + customer name, phone.  If fail, return 500 + SQL error message.

Advantage of Strategy 1 : better experience for end-user ( custom friendly error message ) and calls to CUD operations are never attempted if pre-determined to fail due to required records not present.

Advantages of Strategy 2 : less calls to database per call to web endpoint. How important is this typically ?  Are there other advantages ?

EDIT : I'm trying out Aaron Bertrands upsert and trying to retrieve identity of new row inserted but always zero:

```
BEGIN TRAN

INSERT [dbo].[Auto]
([Make],[Model],[Year],[Customer]) 
SELECT @make, @model, @year, @customerId
WHERE NOT EXISTS
(SELECT 1 
FROM [dbo].[Auto] WITH (UPDLOCK, SERIALIZABLE)
WHERE [Make] = @make
AND [Model] = @model
AND [Year] = @year
AND [Customer] = customerId)

IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0
BEGIN
  UPDATE [dbo].[Auto] 
  SET [Make] = @make
     ,[Model] = @model
     ,[Year] = @year
     ,[Customer] = @customerId
WHERE [Make] = @make
AND [Model] = @model
AND [Year] = @year
AND [Customer] = @customerId)
END

SET @id = SCOPE_IDENTITY()

COMMIT
```

Comment: You have to decide your requirements here... its not something we can decide for you.

Comment: "if found then proceed with SP insert" - That does not sound like how it should work

Comment: Perhaps you would like to read [sql-server-upsert-patterns-and-antipatterns/](https://michaeljswart.com/2017/07/sql-server-upsert-patterns-and-antipatterns/)

Comment: I see it as a trade-off equation. If users are not sophisticated, it's preferred to not present them with raw SQL Server errors.  Preferable is something like "Mike Jones 111-222-3333 not found in our Customer database - please check your information".  But doubling calls to database may be an unacceptable tradeoff.

Answer (score 2):

This question would be opinion-based if it weren't for the fact that Strategy 1 has absolutely no benefit.

You don't need multiple calls to get a friendly error message.  Just call the stored procedure (or ad-hoc SQL batch).  If it fails, catch the exception and send an appropriate and helpful HTTP response.

If extra logic is required, put it *inside* the stored procedure.

Comment: Thanks David. I'm reading some of the articles Stu (in)directly links to above.  It seems that concurrency/deadlocks issues can't be improved/resolved by moving some logic from SQL tier to C# tier.  These issues need to be resolved strictly in the SQL tier.  Is this correct ?

Comment: There are client-side solutions to concurrency issues too, but server-side implementations for these can be more efficient.

Comment: Do you consider it a language/database flaw that SQL Server `UPDATE WHERE PK = @param` does not throw exception where no record exists for `PK = @param` ?

Comment: No.  SQL is a set-based language, and the empty set is a perfectly good set.  Also you can always check the @@rowcount function.